# Implementar números aleatorios en una matriz multidimensional

Tags: php

Realizando un ejercicio académico me he topado con el siguiente problema, rellenar con números aletorios una matriz multidimensional.

Dada la matriz:

```
$data = array(
            array (0,1,2,3,4,5),
            array (0,1,2,3,4,5),
            array (0,1,2,3,4,5),
            array (0,1,2,3,4,5),
            array (0,1,2,3,4,5)           
        );
```

Se han de sustituir los elementos `(0,1,2,3,4,5)` por números aletorios dentro de intevalo [0,9].

Para ello he usado la siguiente función y la he almecenado en una variable :

```
        const  min = 0;
        const max = 9;
        $random = rand(min, max);
```

Mi problema reace a la hora de implenetar esta variable dentro de la matriz sin errores. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: te da error? indica cual es, por otro lado a que te refieres con clara y elegante?

Comment: No sé como implementarlo directamente, poner en cada posición un número aleatorio. Me refiero realizarlo de una manera clara.

Comment: entonces te sugiero editar y escribir eso en tu último renglón, para evitar te voten negativo pues eso no era claro

Answer (score 3):

Te comento lo siguiente, la implementación sería de este modo

```
<?php

const  min = 0;
const max = 9;
$random = rand(min, max);

$data = array(
    array($random, $random, $random, $random, $random),
    array($random, $random, $random, $random, $random),
    array($random, $random, $random, $random, $random),
    array($random, $random, $random, $random, $random),
    array($random, $random, $random, $random, $random)
);


foreach($data as $numero){
    foreach($numero as $elemento){
        echo $elemento;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Sin embargo el resultado sería como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo anterior por que en cada posición se estaría llamando a la misma variable, por lo que aunque aleatorios, va a ser el mismo número en cada posición de la matriz

¿Entonces cómo debería ser dicha implementación?

- Declara tus dos constantes para indicar los números que será usados como límites
- Usa la función `rand()` en cada posición de los `arrays`
- A cada declaración de la función `rand()` pásale como argumentos las constantes declaradas

Quedando así

```
<?php

const  min = 0;
const max = 9;

$data = array(
    array(rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max)),
    array(rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max)),   
    array(rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max)),
    array(rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max)),
    array(rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max), rand(min, max))
);


foreach($data as $numero){
    foreach($numero as $elemento){
        echo $elemento;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Dando como resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mi problema era lo que tú exponías en el primer ejemplo, al generar solamente un número aleatorio todas las posiciones se quedarían con el mismo valor. Desconocía que podías generar directamente dentro la posición un nuevo valor con la función `rand` solamente pasándole de nuevo las constantes `min` `max`. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta de nuevo.

Comment: recuerda @nauumb que tanto para esta pregunta como para la anterior que hiciste puedes marcar como aceptada aquella respuesta que te fue útil y así queda indicado que ya esta solucionada